# Toyota Prius 2011 Model Grades

Tags: toyota, prius

I went through loads and loads of user manuals and all were in Japanese. Could someone please let me know the differences between the **G**, **G Touring**, **S** and **S touring** trim levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.tradecarview.com/specifications/toyota/prius/#month201112):
The **S** and the **G** weigh 1350 kg and have a turning radius of 5.2 m, whereas their **Touring** version weighs 1380 kg and has a turning radius of 5.5 m.

According to [this other site](https://www.pakwheels.com/forums/member-opinions-suggestions/247539-prius-grade-version-awareness):

- L is the base model
- S adds: fog lamps, rear wiper, driver side door smart lock
- G: same as S, plus cruise control, 3 side smart (driver, passenger, rear), power seats
- S Touring: same as S, plus LED headlights, headlight washers, 17" rims, touring suspension
- G Touring: same as S Touring, heads-up display, park assist, lane assist, navigation system, bluetooth controls on steering wheel,
  There is also package called G Touring Leather which adds leather seats and seat heater for front 2 seats.